# Do I have to await an async method?

Tags: c#, asynchronous

I use a `HttpClient` that only supports async methods. Do I have to `await` them in the calling method (not in the async method itself, I have to await the calls in `HttpClient` methods as far as I know)?

I don't really need multithreading in that project. I would be fine blocking and waiting until I get a response from `HttpClient` as I need to have the data anyway. This is a `Console` application.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/14455293/3956100

Comment: If you need a result back - you `await` for it.

Answer (score 4):

No, nothing requires you to `await` the call.  The call is just returning a `Task<T>` to you, rather than a `T` directly. If you call the `Result` property on the `Task`:

```
var result = client.MakeCallAsync().Result;
```

You are telling it "I don't care if it blocks, I want my code (and this thread) to wait here till this is done."

Answer (score 2):

> I don't really need multithreading in that project.

`async` is about asynchrony, not multithreading.

> I would be fine blocking and waiting until I get a response from HttpClient as I need to have the data anyway. This is a Console application.

In this case, then, I'd just say to keep everything synchronous. That is, use `WebClient` instead of `HttpClient`.